# Using geom_abline() and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a beginner in `ggplot2`--it's been only 4 days since I have started experimenting with it. So, I apologize if this question sounds too basic. I'd appreciate any guidance--I've been struggling with this issue for about an hour.

I was experimenting with using `geom_abline()` as below:

```
 p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + geom_point()
 p + geom_abline() + facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

This works as in I can see a reference line in all four faceted graphs as below:

[image]

Later, I was using another related dataset `mtcars` to see what happens to `geom_abline()`

```
  p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
     p + geom_abline() + facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

However, when I ran this command, I couldn't see `geom_abline().` Quite surprisingly, I found similar version of above command in the help file, and it says "*`geom_abline()` is out of the range*"

While I know what "out of range" means, but how do I know whether in a particular dataset, `abline()` will be out of range? I can override it by forcing it to use a specific slope and an intercept, but then I'd consider this a bit of hacking--i.e. modifying the code after seeing the output. Is there any way I can know what happens behind the scenes for `geom_abline()`

Here's the graph I got without any `abline()`s
[image]

I'd appreciate any thoughts. I am really confused.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't give any arguments, `geom_abline()` uses default values, `intercept = 0` and `slope = 1`.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + geom_point() + geom_abline() + lims(x = c(0,35), y = c(0,50))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() + geom_abline() + lims(x = c(0,6), y = c(0,35))
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 7):

The difference between the first plot and the 2nd plot, in terms of the presence of the abline, is not determined by differences in datasets. You asked:

> how do I know whether in a particular dataset, abline() will be out of
>   range?

It actually depends on the scales of two variables thrown in your aesthetics (i.e your two mapping variables). If you notice carefully in the script plotting the `mpg` data, you're comparing `hwy` with `city`. Let's examine each of these closer:

```
range(mpg$hwy)
[1] 12 44
range(mpg$cty)
[1]  9 35
```

As you can see, the range of the variables overlaps quite a bit. Now let's look at the two variables mapped in the second plot using the `mtcars` data -`mpg` and `wt`:

```
range(mtcars$mpg)
[1] 10.4 33.9
range(mtcars$wt)
[1] 1.513 5.424
```

Here you can see there is **zero** overlap and that's why you don't see it when you graph it like below:

[image]

Now let's test notion of range using data that is in range but drawn from the `mtcars` dataset, in order to show its not the dataset but the overlapping ranges of the variables chosen to map. In `mtcars` lets stick with `mpg` and then pick another variable within its range -how bout `qsec`? Let's check their ranges:

```
range(mtcars$mpg)
[1] 10.4 33.9
range(mtcars$qsec)
[1] 14.5 22.9
```

OK, there is definitely some overlap there. Let's map it and see what happens:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) + geom_point() + geom_abline() + facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

[image]

Some additional confirmation it's not dataset dependent. Let's reverse our workflow and instead identify non-overlapping pairs in the `mpg` dataset. Here, we should expect to see no abline. Let's stick with `hwy` and compare it to `displ`. Take my word for it, they do not overlap:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + geom_point()+geom_abline() + facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

[image]

And as others pointed out (@cuttlefish44), `geom_abline()` defaults with an intercept of 0 and slope of 1).

Try using `geom_smooth()` for lines of fit.

```
 p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + geom_point()
 p + geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) + facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Look at the help for `geom_abline()`. There's an example with the same data set that shows — without the facets — that:

```
p + geom_abline() # Can't see it - outside the range of the data
```

Try:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
p + geom_abline(intercept = 20) + facet_wrap(~cyl)
```